# Can't read Azure configuration settings from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I'm running a Node.js application in Azure and am trying to get configuration settings like this:

```
var azure = require('azure');

azure.RoleEnvironment.getConfigurationSettings(function(error, settings) {
   if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return;
   }

   console.log('Settings: %s', settings);
});
```

But the output is always this:

```
{ "code": "ENOENT", "errno": "ENOENT", "syscall": "connect", "fileName": "\\\\.\\pipe\\WindowsAzureRuntime" }
```

I'm running Node.Js within IIS using IISNode using all the latest bits.  I also get the same error if I run node manually on the Azure VM (i.e. node.exe server.js).  Same when running on my PC in the Azure Development Fabric.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Found a working solution for getting ServiceConfiguration.cscfg setting values to Node.Js running within IISNode.  For example, to make a setting named "TestSetting" accessible to Node as environment variables in IISNode, the following must be added to the ServiceDefintion.csdef:

`<Runtime>
   <Environment>
      <Variable name="TestSetting">
         <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/ConfigurationSettings/ConfigurationSetting[@name='TestSetting']/@value" />
      </Variable>
   </Environment>
</Runtime>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned you're running in IISNode, it must be a web role.  Note the following from the [SDK readme](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node):

> The Service Runtime allows you to interact with the machine environment where the current role is running. Please note that these commands **will only work if your code is running in a worker role** inside the Azure emulator or in the cloud.

Comment: Gotcha, had not seen that.  I'm testing this out now running as a worker role starting node via startup task.  And I'm able to pass configuration settings to node via environment settings, which is nice.  However, I'm still getting the same error even running as a worker role.  I see other people claiming to have it working so I must be missing something, but no idea what...

Comment: I have it working here (double checked before I replied). You're getting exactly the same error?  You're not trying to run IISNode within that Worker Role are you?

Comment: No, no IISNode in the worker role.  :)  Just starting it via startup task.  So if the Azure Node.JS client cannot access the Azure configuration settings then what is the recommended approach for providing configuration settings to node when running in IISNode?  Obviously putting settings in the web.config won't suffice since I cannot change it without creating a new package, and node isn't started via startup task when run under IISNode, so I cannot provide settings that way...  Not sure how else to do it...?

Comment: When running under a worker role the error written the console actually looks like this `Error: connect ENOENT`, not quite the same output but appears to be the same error.  But I am now calling azure.RoleEnvironment.isAvailable(...), which returns that error and 'false' for the second isAvailable parameter.  But I don't really care how I get the configuration values, but I would prefer to stick  with IISNode if possible.  So if the Azure Node.js client won't do this I'm more than happy to take another route.

Comment: is that running dev fabric or deployed?  I honestly didn't try deploying it, but got it working (and Web Role did NOT) in emulator.  Pinging some folks internally to see if I can get an answer why IISNode is a factor here.

Comment: I'm seeing the same result running in the dev fabric and in the cloud.  Also in case you need it I'm using Azure SDK 1.7.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Figured out why the Azure Node.js Client wasn't working in my worker role.  I was starting node from a startup task bat file instead of using EntryPoint/ProgramEntryPoint in csdef to start node.  I'm am now able to get 'true' back from azure.RoleEnvironment.isAvailable when running in the dev fabic, so mystery solved there.  But to my original question, I really want node to work under IISNode if possible, still not sure how to get config settings to node in that scenario.

Comment: at this point you just can't unfortunately - the named piped that's used isn't opened in the web role case and is reliant on the Azure runtime which is the roadblock here.  The only way you could do this now is proxy the call through a worker role (x-small probably :))

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It is not good, but at least it works for now.

1. Create a .NET console application like this

   using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace CloudConfigurationHelper
   {
       class Program
       {
           static int MaxRetryTime = 10;

   ```
       public static Dictionary<string, string> GetSettings(string[] keys)
       {
           Dictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

           try
           {
               foreach (string key in keys)
               {
                   settings[key] = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(key);
               }
           }
           catch
           {
               MaxRetryTime--;

               if (MaxRetryTime <= 0)
               {
                   return settings;
               }

               Thread.Sleep(2000);
               return GetSettings(keys);
           }

           return settings;
       }

       static int Main(string[] args)
       {
           var settings = GetSettings(args);
           if (settings.Count != args.Length)
           {
               return -1;
           }

           foreach (string key in settings.Keys)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(key + "=" + settings[key]);
           }

           return 0;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Put start-up task to read the azure configuration variable and write to .env file. Use https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv to read .env file and load to process.env.

Env.cmd file:

```
@echo off
cd %~dp0
CloudConfigurationHelper.exe %*
```

Add start-up task to ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<Task commandLine="Env.cmd YOUR_SETTING_KEY &gt; ..\.env executionContext="elevated" />
```

3. In NodeJS web role, we just need to read this variable via `process.env["YOUR_SETTING_KEY"]`

Comment: Should it perhaps be process.env instead of .evn ?